# jQuery cancelling image load when window.location is set

Tags: jquery, image, window.location

This is my code:

```
if(resp.status > 0)
{
    $('#download-stuff').html('<img src="/public/images/tick.png" alt="Ready" /> Your download should start shortly');
    window.location = 'http://site.com/download.php/' + fileID + '/' + resp.ticket;
} else {
    alert("you have downloaded too much");
}
```

The problem is that when I change the HTML of the `download-stuff` div, the image `tick.png` doesn't appear. After some debugging, it seems that the `window.location` call makes the browser cancel any pending requests, like the one for the tick icon, so it doesn't appear on the page.

Is there a way to get around this that doesn't involve preloading the image on the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple: just start out with the image present but hidden:

```
<div id="download-stuff" style="display:none"> 
    <img id="downloadTick" src="/public/images/tick.png" alt="Ready"/>
    Your download should start shortly
</div>
```

Then in your jQuery code show the image only if the download is about to start:

```
if(resp.status > 0)
{
    $('#download-stuff').show();
    window.location = 'http://site.com/download.php/' + fileID + '/' + resp.ticket;
} else {
    alert("you have downloaded too much");
}
```